# NullPointerException at: int start = Math.max(chat.first, chat.last-10);

Tags: java

I have the following Java code in a JSP:

```
21:     ChatState chat = (ChatState)application.getAttribute(ChatConstants.APP_STATE);
22:     // assert(chat != null);
23: 
24:     int start = Math.max(chat.first, chat.last-10);
25:     for (int i=start; i<chat.last; i++) {
26:     out.println(i + "User Says: " + chat.chat.get(i));
27:     }
```

Line 24 throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.chat_jsp._jspService(chat_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: It seems that the `chat` instance returned at line `21` is `null`.

Comment: How have you set the application attribute `ChatConstants.APP_STATE`?

Comment: That can also happen if `chat.first` or `chat.last` returns an `Integer` instead of `int`. An `Integer` of `null` is not autoboxable to `0` and would throw NPE when doing math on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your chat object is coming **null** here.

Please check

1.the web.xml file, if the application state variables are initialised there

or

2.the position where you have written -

```
application.setAttribute(/*some code snippet*/)
```

or

3.you can check whether these attributes are set from any properties file or not

Probably these checking should give you the pointer to the problem.